# Remove row index from query result of codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i'm new in codeigniter, and i have a little problem (not really a problem) getting results from query.

Use this code as example:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT u_id FROM users WHERE u_email={$email} AND u_password=PASSWORD({$password}) ;");
print_r($query->result());
```

It returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [u_id] => 1
        )
)
```

Can i remove the row index? Fetching results using something similar next code is horrible:

```
foreach( as $info){
    print_r($info);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure your `foreach` can work?

Comment: Hi Calos, i miss the $query->result_array() inside the foreach, sorry :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know your query will return only one row then use the appropriate CI function to get just one row, then it will not return the result into an array.

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT u_id FROM users WHERE u_email={$email} AND u_password=PASSWORD({$password}) ;");

$row = $query->row();

echo $row->u_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need single value from the result use 
Also use active records for you queries,

```
$this->db->select('u_id');
$this->db->from('users');
$this->db->where('u_email',$email);
$this->db->where('u_password',$password);
return $this->db->get()->row()->u_id ;
```